# c# Interop Create word table and some sub tables

Tags: c#, interop

I'm using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` using C# to creating word document, but i have a problem, 
i want to create table and in a specific column i want to create some sub tables Each table under the others sub table.

I wrote this code but it is not what I need:

```
ProcessTable.Rows[4].Cells[1].Range.Text = "Evidences:";
ProcessTable.Rows[4].Cells[1].Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
ProcessTable.Rows[4].Cells[2].Merge(ProcessTable.Cell(4, 6));



//Create a 1X1 table and insert some dummy record
Table SubTable = document.Tables.Add(ProcessTable.Rows[4].Cells[2].Range, 1, 1);

// to enable borders..
SubTable.Borders.Enable = 1;


ProcessTable.Rows[4].Cells[2].Range.Text = SubTable.Rows[1].Cells[1].Range.Text = "some data";


//Create a 1X1 table and insert some dummy record
Table SubTable2 = document.Tables.Add(SubTable.Rows[1].Cells[1].Range, 1, 1);
ProcessTable.Rows[4].Cells[2].Range.Paragraphs.Add();
// to enable borders..
SubTable2.Borders.Enable = 1;
ProcessTable.Rows[4].Cells[2].Range.Text += SubTable2.Rows[1].Cells[1].Range.Text = "some data";
ProcessTable.Rows[4].Cells[2].Range.Paragraphs.Add();
// 4-Conclusion  
ProcessTable.Rows[5].Cells[1].Range.Text = "Conclusion:";

ProcessTable.Rows[5].Cells[2].Merge(ProcessTable.Cell(5, 6));

ProcessTable.Rows[5].Cells[2].Range.Text = @"DATA ";
```

Comment: What's not right with this code? Where do you think the issue could be? What do you want from this code?

Comment: i need to insert 2 sub tables in  ProcessTable.Rows[4].Cells[2] . the problem is 2 sub tables appear over each other

Comment: What happens with this code? Is it giving any error? What does it create in cell instead of subtable?

Comment: it create 2 sub tables with the same range, so , the 2 tables appear over each other

Comment: `Table SubTable2 = document.Tables.Add(ProcessTable.Rows[4].Cells[2].Range, 1, 1);` didn't help?

Comment: No, it insert SubTable2  over SubTable1 not after it